# ReSharper: Can I make my own context action?

Tags: c#, resharper

ReSharper has a "Check parameter for null" context action, that will automatically insert code to check an argument for null and throw ArgumentNullException if it is null.

If the parameter is a string, I would like another option: "Check string for Null or empty". This should generate code something similar to this:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    throw new ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null or empty", "result");
```

Is there any way to add this to ReSharper easily ?

Comment: [This article](http://hadihariri.com/2010/01/12/writing-plug-ins-for-resharper-part-1-of-undefined/) should give you a good start.

Comment: Resharper 5.0 (currently in RC status) has a new feature called the "Pattern Catalogue" that might be able to help with this. Unfortunately you'll have to pay to upgrade to it.

Comment: @Greg sufficiently-recent purchases of 4.5 qualify for a free upgrade to 5.0 (they don't pay me to say this :))

Comment: How to use Pattern Catalogue in R# 5.0: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/04/introducing-resharper-50-structural-search-and-replace/

Answer (score 5):

I've created ReSharper live templates for *check for null* and *check for empty string*.

So `pnn` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts a parameter not null check etc.

The code for `pnn` looks like this

```
if($ARG$ == null)
   throw new $ARGNULLEXC$("$ARG$");$END$
```

Where `$ARG$` is "Suggest parameter of type System.Object" and `$ARGNULLEXC$` is "insert reference to System.ArgumentNullException". The `$END$` indicates where your cursor should be after inserting the live template.

For the string variant, you would assign `$ARG$` something like "Suggest parameter of type System.String".